# Automatic conversion of false to array is deprecated

Tags: php

I get this warning in a chunk of instructions PHP 8+ dedicated to the check of the user inside the page:

```
if ($_POST['go'] ?? null) {
// $_SESSION_VALUES is an array $db, $nick are classes of mine
    $_SESSION_VALUES = $nick->get_cookie (COOKIE_NAME); // get the name of the cookie
    if ($db->check_user (USERS_TABLE, $_POST['nick'], $db->encode_password($_POST['password']))) {
        $_SESSION_VALUES['_USERNAME'] = $db->user_rec['nick'];  // get the nickname from the cookie
        $_SESSION_VALUES['_PASSWORD'] = $db->user_rec['password']; //get the password
        $_SESSION_VALUES['_USER'] = $db->user_type;
        if (! $nick->set_cookie (COOKIE_NAME, $_SESSION_VALUES)) die ('Cannot write the cookie');           // record the cookie
        header('Location: ./copertina'); }
        else $_SESSION_VALUES['_USER']  = -1;
    }
```

The execution of

```
else $_SESSION_VALUES['_USER']  = -1;
```

gives "Automatic conversion of false to array is deprecated"

Following a suggestion from stack overflow I tryed this:

```
$\_SESSION_VALUES = \[\];

if ($\_POST\['go'\] ?? null) {

...
```

but apparently it doesn't work

any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `$nick->get_cookie(COOKIE_NAME);` returns `false`.

Try changing:

```
    else $_SESSION_VALUES['_USER']  = -1;
```

to:

```
   else $_SESSION_VALUES = ['_USER' => -1];
```

This will probably get rid of the error message you reported, but I don't know if the rest of your code, which I cannot see, will accept this.